# What is the upper bound on the Diameter of a connected Graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am writing a program in Java where I have to store the shortest path for each vertex in a two-dimensional array. I know the number of verticies, so the number of rows is known but I don't know the number of columns. I mean a shortest path could have any arbitary length. But is there a bound that caps this value?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest path cannot go through any vertex more than once (otherwise, you'd cut off the loop between those two passings-through). So the number of vertices, minus 1, is an upper bound.

(This assumes that all the "edge lengths" are either 1, or at least nonnegative)